# Can i use RESTAssured API for SOAP Web Service Automation

Tags: java, web-service, rest-api

I know , i can use RESTAssureed API for REST web service automation.

But, can i use REST Assured API to automate SOAP web services. or are there any other way to automate SOAP web service using Java

Comment: There is tool available SOAP UI for soap and rest API testing which you can use to automate SOAP API  https://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can, however that would be quite a tricky thing, since you will have to take care of forming request body (envelopes) and parse the responses in order to make your requests comply with SOAP protocol. But initially RESTAssured is not intended to work with web-services.

If you use Java I would recommend you to use one of the following ways to generate client classes which will let you interact with your web service very easily:

1. Java built-in tool [wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/wsimport.htm#JSWOR740)
2. Apache CFX tool set

   2.1. [Generate using command line](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

   2.2. [Generate using Maven plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html)

Basically you set WSDL URL when use those tools and they generate you the classes which hide any protocl-specific things from you and you just work with Web Service as with simple Java object.